# Rendering colors and images looks different in iPhone 4 compared to iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, colors

Colors and images looks different if you compared it on iPhone 4 or iPhone 5, specially greens. This is normal since they have different screens but is there a way to fix it? We are using some colors & assets that look awful on the iPhone 4, I could add some extra offset for the colors to try to match the RGB we are looking for, but what about images?

This is a screen of the app, if you will try opening it in the iphone 4 and 5 to see the difference.(with full brightness)

[image: IMAGE TEST]

Comment: The two devices are different. Little chance that same RGB colors will appear the same way.

Comment: You could detect device type on application launch and adjust colors accordingly. At least thats what i would do in this case.